# Laravel 5(.7) Organizing Model/Collection With Multiple Relations

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following Eloquent query that makes heavy use of [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships) on models and it works.

Here it is:

```
$trip = ModelLocale::where("lang",$lang)
                    ->where("slug",$slug)
                    ->where('mainmodel_id',$id)
                    ->with(['mainmodel' => function ($query) use ($id)
                    {
                        $query
                            ->where('id', $id)
                            ->with(['convertedPrices' => function ($nestedQuery) use($id)
                            {
                                $nestedQuery
                                    ->where('model_id', $id)
                                    ->where('currency', Function::getCurrency());
                            }])
                            ->with(['othermodel','othermodel2', /** */, 'othermodel5']);
                    }])
                    ->first();
```

Anyway, this works and is just an illustration.

My problem is I get back a lot of nested relationships and it is a bit disorganized when it goes to the view.

I have another member of my team and either the eloquent relationships or specific way we make this query may change, but the view will more or less always need the same data. Therefore, I want to organize/sanitize this query and standardize it before passing it to my view.

Does this make sense?

I understand each return from Eloquent is an instance of this - [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections).

But I am having some issues dealing with the various methods here because when I `dd()` my collection I see so many properties and nests.

What is the recommended way to manipulate this big collection while keeping the integrity of the various relationship models? For example, this query would return a `ModelLocale` at the top, then a relationship property (among other properties that I don't need - like `perPage` and `wasRecentlyCreated`) with another model, then more nested relationships on this second model. I want to combine the first two models and just have relationships of the *one* parent.

So for example, when I `dd` I get:

```
-Model 1:
--Many properties
--Relations:
---Model 2
----Many properties
----Relations:
-----Model 3
-----Model 4
-----etc
```

Is there an easy way so when I am in the view, instead of...

```
$model->model_relationship->model_relationship->atrribute
```

...I can reorganize these around and merge the two first models? Or rename and map through the relations and attributes while ignoring the extraneous properties and make a very simple array of properties for the view?

Sorry this isn't extremely specific, I can't show exact values from my database and the point is that it will change... so I am looking for general guidance on this kind of reorganization of collections.

I am more comfortable with JSON than this, and I am bit intimidated by the structure of the collection, as I read somewhere collections ["are like arrays on steroids"](https://scotch.io/tutorials/laravel-collections-php-arrays-on-steroids).

Here is a sample of the collection:

```
ModelLocale {#246 ▼
  #fillable: array:1 [▶]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "model_locales"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:8 [▼
    "id" => 580
    "main_model_id" => 290
    "title" => "Dolor dolores et hic."
    "slug" => "dolor-dolores-et-hic"
    "body" => "Enim consequuntur aliquam et iste aut incidunt corporis voluptates. Est sapiente doloribus est inventore delectus. Quia sequi doloremque nesciunt nulla non minu ▶"
    "lang" => "fj"
    "created_at" => "2019-01-16 19:17:43"
    "updated_at" => "2019-01-16 19:17:43"
  ]
  #original: array:8 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: array:1 [▼
    "MainModel" => MainModel{#255 ▼
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      #hidden: array:2 [▶]
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "mainmodels"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:16 [▼
        "id" => 290
        "model2_id" => 17
        "model3_id" => 0
        "model4_id" => 451
        "price" => "385.00"
        "created_at" => "2019-01-16 19:17:42"
        "updated_at" => "2019-01-16 19:17:43"
      ]
      #original: array:16 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:7 [▼
        "model3" => Model 3{#267 ▶}
        "model4" => Model 4{#264 ▶}
        "model5" => Model 5{#307 ▼
          #guarded: array:1 [▶]
          #connection: "mysql"
          #table: "model5s"
          #primaryKey: "id"
          #keyType: "int"
          +incrementing: true
          #with: []
          #withCount: []
          #perPage: 15
          +exists: true
          +wasRecentlyCreated: false
          #attributes: array:7 [▶]
          #original: array:7 [▶]
          #changes: []
          #casts: []
          #dates: []
          #dateFormat: null
          #appends: []
          #dispatchesEvents: []
          #observables: []
          #relations: []
          #touches: []
          +timestamps: true
          #hidden: []
          #visible: []
          #fillable: []
        }
        "model6" => Collection {#311 ▶}
        "model7" => Collection {#312 ▶}
        "model8" => null
        "model9" => Collection {#368 ▶}
      ]
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
    }
  ]
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}
```

So I have `ModelLocale`, which has a relationship with `MainModel` which in turn has several relationships with the other models. But I just want a very simple (as much as possible) array of the attributes I care about - because again the nesting or relationships may change...

Comment: Could you provide a sample (one or two elements per level) of your use case? to get to know a little more about your needs. There is a lot of manner to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: By the way, related to when you do `dd()` on a Collection. Yes, you'll see all the properties that are available in the class, if you want it the array version just call the [`->toArray()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-toarray) method on the collection: `dd($my_collection->toArray());`. And yes, Collections are awesome, they have a [ton of useful methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#available-methods) to manipulate collections fo items.

Comment: @HCK added a representation of the collection, hope that helps you with your appreciated assistance, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are two things I would suggest.

First, limit the query to eager load only specific columns when possible.

> You may not always need every column from the relationships you are retrieving. For this reason, Eloquent allows you to specify which columns of the relationship you would like to retrieve:

```
$users = App\Book::with('author:id,name')->get();
```

Second, use a response transformer - see [Eloquent: API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-resources) - to shape the data before sending the response. This guarantees the data you need in a set format.

These two things will both reduce the response payload and provide a sane, organized structure.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer! Correct me if I'm wrong but the Eloquent resources are from JSON output correct? It says this in the documentation you linked me to. Furthermore, just so my question is clear, it is not necessarily all the columns on the various models that is problematic for me (I know about the specific eager loading you mention) but the fact of the structure of the models in a hierarchical nest that depends on specific relationships - which may change - to pass data to the view. I would prefer this nesting was not the final data passed to the view...

Comment: Also the overwhelming nature of the collection is due to properties on it that aren't my model columns - see the sample I added above in my question edit, but I will try as some of the comments suggested to use `toArray()`